# Gretl - How to extract sub-series?

Tags: software

I have series with 62 observations. How do I create a series with just the first 26 observations so that I can run an estimation on it?

Sorry, really really beginner with gretl. I tried the square bracket but it just gives a single element. (I know general purpose programming languages very well.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to chapter 7 of Gretl's User Guide (.pdf format), titled "Sub-sampling a dataset".